# SUMO Traffic Simulator - Find neighbouring traffic lights

Tags: sumo, traffic

I have this simple SUMO simulation

```
traci.start(["sumo", "-c", ".\sumo_test_simulation\sumoconfig.sumo.cfg"])

steps = 0
waiting_times = {}
waiting_cars = {}
while steps < n:
    traci.simulationStep()
    (...)
    steps += 1
```

I can't find a way to get neighbouring traffic lights of a single traffic light(selected by id, for example)???